# Is it possible to integrate the wave launcher with other applications?

Tags: android

I wanted to integrate the wave launcher app with my app that I am building, so I could display the menu page of my app in that wave form. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In general any question like: "Is it possible to integrate with [SOME_APPLICATION]" can be answered by: "Only if [SOME_APPLICATION.DEVELOPER] has created some API for you to use, or if you can manage to get in touch with them and figure out some other way to integrate." If you can't find any section on their site about integrating with other apps (in any manner that isn't advertised i.e. more than just adding the shortcut to the wave thing) chances are good that it is not possible, and your best bet is to reach out to the people who made it.

Comment: I had seen an API for the iphone, so was wondering if any API was released for the android. Guess not.